"error": "415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
I am working on a React-Python(Flask) project. I keep getting the error in the backend:

'415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'.

and on the frontend:

'student-register.tsx:93 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'

I don't know whether the issue is with the backend side or the frontend side. I have rechecked my React endpoint and I don't see where the problem:
export const StudentRegister = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = async (values: any) => {
    try {
      const formData = new FormData()
      
      if (values.image && values.image.length > 0) {
        formData.append('image', values.image[0].originFileObj);
        console.log(formData)
      }  
      
      const imageResponse = await fetch('/facial-data', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      })

      const imageResult = await imageResponse.json();
      console.log('Image upload response:', imageResult);

      delete values.image;

      const formResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/student', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });

      const data = await formResponse.json();

      if (formResponse.ok) {
        message.success(data.message);
        form.resetFields();
        
      } else {
        message.error(data.error);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }

    window.location.href = '/login';
  };

  return ()

And my flask endpoint also looks okay to:
@app.route('/student', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    print(request.headers)
    print("---------")
    print(request.data)
    session = Session()

    try:
        data = request.json
        user = User(
            first_name=data.get('firstname'),
            last_name=data.get('lastname'),
            email=data.get('email'),
            reg_no=data.get('reg_no'),
            role=data.get('role'),
            password=data.get('password')
        )
        user.save_to_db(session)

        response = {'message': 'Registration successful'}
        return jsonify(response), 200
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500
    finally:
        session.close()

What could be the issue? Any help will be appreciated.
I tried to print the header and got:
Host: localhost:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: Pycharm-119ea720=95741790-f49e-4011-8331-67c2c03dcc92; _ga=GA1.1.1648027930.1713378416; _ga_ZLVG7NETWG=GS1.1.1713532635.4.1.1713533069.0.0.0; _ga_1M7M0TRFHS=GS1.1.1713532635.4.1.1713533069.0.0.0; _ga_K62YRZRY27=GS1.1.1713532635.4.1.1713533069.0.0.0


---------
b''

looks like the request headers are correct, and the request body (request.data) is empty (b'').
I also tried to console.log(JSON.stringify(values)) and the form values are being fed correctly into the onfinish function.

When printing the request header, you don't get the application/json value in the Content-type key. Make sure to post it in the request header.

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, could you explain a bit more please

I see that the value (Content-Type) of the front sent in the header of your request has not been received.Ensure that this value is sent correctly to the backend or
one solution in your backend (Flask) is using data = request.form instead of data = request.json
